# AVAudioPlayer volume range?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, avaudioplayer

We used AVAudioPlayer in Cocos2d project. Audio variation is not as expected.

CODE:

```
    NSURL* tapSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                              pathForResource:@"tap"
                                              ofType:@"m4a"]];

    mClickSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: tapSound error: nil];
    [mClickSound prepareToPlay];
    mClickSound.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [mClickSound setVolume: 1.0f];

    mRandomLoopMusic = NULL;
```

In above code, I set volume 1.0, but music volume is not full. When I set 10.0f then increases. So my doubt is what is the range of volume? In doc of AVAudioPlayer, 0 - 1 is range, but in cocos2D sample its not true. How can we limit audio range to 0 - 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the volume of the device itself, you should set

```
[mClickSound setVolume:1.0];
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
```

You'll also need to add the MediaPlayer framework

Comment: sorry sir...its not right answer...my question is how to restrict AVAudioPlayer's volume range....it works even if it is 1.5 :)